# Is there a ChangeNotifierList?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

Is there a List class that implements ChangeNotifier?  Basically if anything is added to the list or the list is rearranged it will call notifyListeners?

Answer (score 1):

No. But here's one:

```dart
class ChangeNotifierList<T> with ListMixin<T>, ChangeNotifier {
  ChangeNotifierList(this._internalList);

  final List<T> _internalList;

  @override
  int get length => _internalList.length;

  @override
  T operator [](int index) {
    return _internalList[index];
  }

  @override
  void operator []=(int index, T value) {
    _internalList[index] = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  set length(int newLength) {
    _internalList.length = newLength;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: And if you're worried about performance (since `ListMixin` can have poor performance for adding elements), you can do the same thing with `DelegatingList`, with a little more code.